# List<> from Room Database is always null

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-livedata

The following classes are used to store a list of surveys in a Room database. LiveData is used to be able to update

Entity class for Database:

```
@Entity
public class Survey {

@PrimaryKey
@NonNull
private String surveyID;
private String surveyName;
private String url;
private double lat;
private double lng;
private  double radius;

public Survey(String surveyID, String surveyName, double lat, double lng, double radius, String url) {
    this.surveyID = surveyID;
    this.surveyName = surveyName;
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lng = lng;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.url = url;
}
```

Respective Dao Interface:

```
@Dao
public interface SurveyDao {

@Query("SELECT * FROM Survey")
LiveData<List<Survey>> getListOfSurveys();

/* Rest omitted */
}
```

Respective Repository class

```
public class SurveyRepository {

private final SurveyDao surveyDao;

@Inject
public SurveyRepository (SurveyDao surveyDao){
    this.surveyDao = surveyDao;
}

public LiveData<List<Survey>> getListOfSurveys(){
    return surveyDao.getListOfSurveys();
}
/* Rest omitted */
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class SurveyCollectionViewModule extends ViewModel {

private SurveyRepository repository;

public SurveyCollectionViewModule(SurveyRepository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
}

public LiveData<List<Survey>> getSurveys(){
    return repository.getListOfSurveys();
}
/* Rest Omitted */
}
```

Using all of this, I have setup a Fragment which has a RecyclerView displaying the list of surveys. The list is obtained in the following way:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    surveyCollectionViewModule = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory)
            .get(SurveyCollectionViewModule.class);

    surveyCollectionViewModule.getSurveys().observe(this, new Observer<List<Survey>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Survey> surveys) {
            if(SurveyListFragment.this.listOfSurveys == null) {
                setSurveyData(listOfSurveys);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

However, I am running into the problem, where the call to `getItemCount()` in the adapter fails due to this list being `NULL`. The database does not contain any entries but I am still at a lost as to why the list is always returning as null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `onChanged` doesn't actually use the `surveys` parameter it is given, change it to call `setSurveyData(surveys)` to actually fill out your data.

Answer (score 0):

make some changes in ViewModel class like below ...

```
    private final LiveData<List<Survey>> SurveyList;

private AppDatabase appDatabase;

public SurveyCollectionViewModule(Application application) {
    appDatabase = AppDatabase.getDatabase(this.getApplication());

    SurveyList = appDatabase.surveyDao().getAllSurvey();
}
public LiveData<List<Survey>> getSurveys() {
    return SurveyList;
}
```